# Alert function in cordova app returns [object, Object]

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm trying to use cordova local notification plugin with my cordova app, it works fine, but the function to return scheduled notifications shows [object, Object] in the alert box, this is what i've tried

```
var callbackOpts = function(notifications) {
    //.log(notifications);
    navigator.notification.alert(notifications.length === 0 ? '- none -' : notifications.join(', '));
    var count = notifications.length;
    document.getElementById("reminderCount").innerHTML = count;
};

function getScheduled() {
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.getScheduled(callbackOpts);
    document.getElementById("reminderCount").innerHTML = count;
}
```

Please help
This is the notification format

```
 cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
            id: btn.dataset.id,
            title: btn.dataset.name,
            text: "Your Bus Will Be At The Station In " + changedTime + " Minutes",
            trigger: { in: btn.dataset.diff, unit: 'minute' },
            sound: "file://js/when.mp3",
            icon: "file://img/mmArtboard.png"
            });
```

Comment: what is the type of elements in notifications array ?

if the type is an object you will get alert as [object, object].


`notifications = [{},{}]`
`Array [ {}, {} ]`

`notifications.join(',')`
`"[object Object],[object Object]"`

Comment: @NijeeshJoshy how am i supposed to correct it please?

Comment: Did you use JSON.stringify? Since its, an object that you are returning it will only show [object object]

Comment: @kunlee, can you tell me how the notification object is structured. if possible post and example. or like @Udit said you can use `JSON.stringify`. may be like this

`notifications.map(JSON.stringify).join(' , ')` this will convert the object to string and join it. But i dont think this is how you are trying to show it on the alert, unless you want to show the alert in JSON format

Comment: @NijeeshJoshy i have edited the question, i added the notification structure

Comment: @kunlee, can you please    `console.log(JSON.stringify(notifications));` and post the output here.

Comment: @NijeeshJoshy, thanks JSON.stringify worked. it returned the data in form of `[{"id":1 "title":"example"}]` something like that, but now i want to output just title from the array, i tried `var myArr = JSON.stringify(notifications); alert(myArr.title); but it returned null`

Comment: `notifications.map((notification)=> notification.title ).join(' , ')` this will give the outputs as `"title-1 , title-2 "` if the arrays is like this `[{ id: 1, title: "title-1"}, { id: 1, title: "title-2"} ]` no need for `JSON.stringify ` anymore since the output is in string

Comment: is the notifications array going be a length of one always ?

Comment: thanks @NijeeshJoshy, resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite a small issue, since the data is in brace brackets before the curly brackets `[{"id":1, "title":"example"}]`, you ave to access the brace brackets first before the curly brackets. This would work =>

```
var callbackOpts = function (notifications) {
    var i;
for (i = 0; i < notifications.length; i++) {
navigator.notification.alert(notifications.length === 0 ? '- none -' : 
notifications[i].title);
}
var count = notifications.length;
};
function getScheduled() {
cordova.plugins.notification.local.getScheduled(callbackOpts);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because when you call `alert()` with an object as a argument before being shown  `.toString()` method will be called on it.

```
>>[{id: 1, title: hello}].toString()
"[object Object]"
```

If you want to show the object as it is you can call `JSON.strignify(notifications)` on it so it will be converted to an string representation of the js object.

if you want so show only the title from the array of objects you can extract only the titles and join them and show it.

```
>>let notifications = [{ id: 1, title: "title-1"}, { id: 1, title: "title-2"} ]
>>notifications.map((notification)=> notification.title ).join(' , ')
"title-1 , title-2 "
```